# yarn install failed for building Spartacus storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I just follow the instructions from https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/contributor-setup/, unfortunately, when i run 'yarn install' in the root directory of cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront, the following error happens:

```
┌ Resolution step

│ fsevents@npm:2.0.7: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged

│ fsevents@npm:2.0.7: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged

│ nan@npm:2.14.0: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged

│ evp_bytestokey@npm:1.0.3: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged

│ storefrontapp@workspace:. doesn't provide jquery@1.9.1 - 3 requested by bootstrap@npm:4.3.1

│ storefrontapp@workspace:. doesn't provide popper.js@^1.14.7 requested by bootstrap@npm:4.3.1

│ storefrontapp@workspace:. provides zone.js@npm:0.10.2 with version 0.10.2 which doesn't satisfy ~0.9.1 requested by @angular/core@npm:8.2.6

│ storefrontapp@workspace:. doesn't provide express@^4.15.2 requested by @nguniversal/express-engine@npm:8.1.1

│ storefrontapp@workspace:. doesn't provide webpack@4.x.x requested by webpack-cli@npm:3.3.7

└ Completed in 37.41s

┌ Fetch step

│ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A2.0.7#builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=2.0.7&hash=e8cd9e can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the disk

│ Error: fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A2.0.7#builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=2.0.7&hash=e8cd9e:
 Cannot apply hunk #1
     at c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js:58:888149)
     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

│ typescript@patch:typescript@npm%3A2.9.1#builtin<compat/typescript>::version=2.9.1&hash=226bd1
 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the disk

│ typescript@patch:typescript@npm%3A2.9.2#builtin<compat/typescript>::version=2.9.2&hash=226bd1
 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the disk

│ Error: typescript@patch:typescript@npm%3A2.9.1#builtin<compat/typescript>::version=2.9.1&hash=226bd1:
 Cannot apply hunk #1
     at c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js:58:888149)
     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

│ Error:typescript@patch:typescript@npm%3A2 .9.2#builtin<compat/typescript>::version=2.9.2&hash=226bd1:
 Cannot apply hunk #1
     at c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js:58:888149)
     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

└ Completed in 1.46m

Failed with errors in 2.08m
```

What's wrong with that? any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide more informations? Spartacus version, `yarn` version, `npm` version, your OS, your IDE, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Those issues are not related to Spartacus, nor are they related to angular-cli. I think your having issues with the installation/setup of node-gyp on mac Catalina.

Can you verify the analyse/solutions at https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md? I went through this myself and solved the same issues locally.